# Retrocausality in Haskell: From Tardis to RevState

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, monads, lazy-evaluation, state-monad

The following program uses a backwards-traveling state as provided by the [Tardis](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tardis) monad.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}

import Control.Monad.Tardis

lastOccurrence :: Int -> Tardis [Int] () Bool
lastOccurrence x = mdo
  sendPast (x : xs)
  xs <- getFuture
  return (not (elem x xs))

lastOccurrences :: [Int] -> Tardis [Int] () [Bool]
lastOccurrences xs = mapM lastOccurrence xs

main :: IO ()
main =
  print $ flip evalTardis ([], ()) $ lastOccurrences [3,4,6,7,4,3,5,7]
```

How can I replace the Tardis monad with the [reverse State](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rev-state) monad?
With my following proposal, `main` loops forever instead of printing
`[False,False,True,False,True,True,True,True]` as with the above program.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RecursiveDo #-}

import Control.Monad.RevState

lastOccurrence :: Int -> State [Int] Bool
lastOccurrence x = mdo
  put (x : xs)
  xs <- get
  return (not (elem x xs))

lastOccurrences :: [Int] -> State [Int] [Bool]
lastOccurrences xs = mapM lastOccurrence xs

main :: IO ()
main =
  print $ flip evalState [] $ lastOccurrences [3,4,6,7,4,3,5,7]
```

Comment: If your question isn't getting enough attention on SO, feel free to ping package authors such as myself! Issue trackers and maintainer contact info can usually be found on hackage, e.g. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/rev-state

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have now downloaded the source of both `Tardis` and `RevState`, and I started hacking on them until they are almost the same:

- I ignored everything outside the `Trans.{Tarids,RevState}` modules, so that I don't have to bother with the typeclasses
- I removed the forward-propagating state of `Tardis`
- I renamed `Tardis` to `State`

After a bit of reordering of code, I ended up in a situation where your `Tardis`-using example still works and your `RevState`-using example still doesn't work, and their difference is minimal.

What is that minimal difference, you ask? Unsurprisingly, the `MonadFix` instance. [`Tardis` has this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tardis-0.3.0.0/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-Tardis.html#line-133):

```
instance MonadFix m => MonadFix (TardisT bw fw m) where
  mfix f = TardisT $ \s -> do
    rec (x, s') <- runTardisT (f x) s
    return (x, s')
```

whereas [`RevState` has this](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/rev-state-0.1/docs/src/Control-Monad-Trans-RevState.html#line-73):

```
instance MonadFix m => MonadFix (StateT s m) where
  mfix f = StateT $ \s ->
    mfix (\(x, _) -> runStateT (f x) s)
```

While they seem similar, the big difference is that the `RevState` one is strict in the tuple constructor, whereas the `Tardis` one is lazy. (see e.g. the [GHC documentation on `RecursiveDo`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#recursive-do-notation) to see that the `Tardis` one desugars into an irrefutable pattern match in the lambda passed to `mfix`).

Indeed, changing the implementation of `RevState` so that

```
instance MonadFix m => MonadFix (StateT s m) where
  mfix f = StateT $ \s -> do
    mfix (\ ~(x, _) -> runStateT (f x) s)
```

fixes your original `RevState`-using program.

Comment: I've reported this as a bug to upstream: https://github.com/DanBurton/rev-state/issues/2

Comment: Author of Tardis and rev-state here. Can confirm, this was a bug. I just uploaded rev-state-0.1.1 with Cactus's suggested fix, and turned this example into a test case. Thanks for looking into that!